# Parsing in bison stops at first line

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc

I am creating a bison grammar in a python like language and the output that i am getting when running my testcode file is this:

```
found identifier a at line 2
memory exhausted

Parsing completed successfully
```

I am getting some shift reduce errors and reduce reduce but i can create normally my .exe file and if i run it it shows this.

I've tried reducing most of my shift/reduces to no vail. Is that really the problem though? Because i think it wouldn't give me an .exe

.l file

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sym_tab.h"
#include "define.h"

FILE *new_file;
int stringtoint;
int current_indent = 0;
void count();
void comment();
int count_indent();

%}



L                  [A-Za-z]
D                  [0-9]
N                  [1-9]
C   "%"|"!"|"@"|"$"|"%"|"^"|"&"|"_"



identifier          {L}({L}|{D})*
dec_const           (-|\+)*(0|{N}{D}*)
blank               [ \v\f]+
invalid_identifier  {D}|{C}(({L}|{D})*|{L})
invalid_keyword     {C}({L}|{D})+
block_count                 ^[\t]+


%%

"while"           {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found keyword %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                        addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(WHILE); }

"for"           {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found keyword %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                        addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(FOR); }
"in range"            {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found keyword %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                        addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(IN_RANGE); }

"input"           {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found keyword %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                        addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(INPUT); }
"print"           {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found keyword %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                        addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(PRINT); }

"if"              {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found keyword %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                        addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(IF); }
"elif"            {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found keyword %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                        addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(ELIF); }
"else"            {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found keyword %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                        addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(ELSE); }

"and"             {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found keyword %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                        addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(AND); }
"not"             {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found keyword %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                        addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(NOT); }
"or"              {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found keyword %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                        addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(OR); }

"return"          {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found keyword %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                        addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(RETURN); }
"exit"            {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found keyword %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                        addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(EXIT); }

"def"             {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found keyword %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                        addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(DEF); }

L?\"(\\.|[^\\"])*\" {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found literal string %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                           addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(STRING_LITERAL); }


{dec_const}               {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); stringtoint=atoi(yycopy);if(stringtoint<(-32768)|| stringtoint>32767){
              printf("dec_const %d in line %d not an acceptable value\n",stringtoint,line);}else{
              printf("found dec_constant %s at line %d\n", yycopy,line);
              addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(DEC_CONST);}}


{identifier}              {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); if(strlen(yycopy)>20){
               printf("identifier %s in line %d not valid(longer than 20 characters)\n",yycopy,line);}
               else{printf("found identifier %s at line %d\n", yycopy,line);
                           addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(IDENTIFIER);}}


"+"                       {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found symbol %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                           addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(PLUS);}
"-"                       {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found symbol %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                           addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(MINUS);}
"*"                       {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found symbol %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                           addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(STAR);}
"/"                       {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found symbol %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                           addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(DIV);}
"<"                       {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found equation_symbol %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                           addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(L_THAN);}
">"                       {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found equation_symbol %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                           addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(G_THAN);}
"=="                      {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found equation_symbol %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                           addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(EQUAL);}
"<="                      {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found equation_symbol %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                           addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(L_EQ_THAN);}
">="                      {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found equation_symbol %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                           addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(G_EQ_THAN);}
"<>"                      {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found equation_symbol %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                           addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(NEQUAL);}
":="                        {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found asign_symbol %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                           addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(ASSIGN);}
"("                       {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                           addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(LPAREN);}
")"                       {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                           addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(RPAREN);}

"["                       {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                           addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(LSQUARE_BRACK);}
"]"                       {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                           addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(RSQUARE_BRACK);}

"\n"                        {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found new line at line %d\n" , line);
                           addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(END_LINE);}
","                       {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                           addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(COMMA);}
":"                                             {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("found %s at line %d\n" ,yycopy, line);
                           addsym( yycopy, block_num ); return(COLON);}

"#"                      { comment();}

{blank}                   { count();}



{invalid_keyword}    {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("invalid keyword %s at line %d\n", yycopy, line);
              addsym( yycopy, block_num );}

{invalid_identifier}   {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("invalid identifier %s at line %d\n", yycopy, line);
              addsym( yycopy, block_num );}


.              {char *yycopy=strdup(yytext); count(); printf("unexpected character %s at line %d\n", yycopy, line);
              addsym( yycopy, block_num );}

%%

int yywrap()
{
  return 1;
}

// void main(int argc, char *argv[]){
//   int ret_val=1;
//
//   if (argc!=2) printf("\nUsage: lexyy <input file name> \n");
//   else
//     if ((new_file=fopen(argv[1],"r"))==NULL)
//       printf("\n<%s> not found.\n",argv[1]);
//     else{
//       yyrestart(new_file);
//       while(ret_val!=0){
//         ret_val=yylex();
//       }
//       fclose(new_file);
//     }
//}

void count()
{
        int i;
        for(i=0;yytext[i]!='\0';i++)
        if(yytext[i]=='\n')
        {
                line++;
        }
}

int count_indent()
{
  int i;
  int tab_num = 0;
  for(i=0;yytext[i]=='\t';i++)
  {
    tab_num++;
  }
  return tab_num;
}


void comment()
{
  int c;
  while(c=input()!='\n' && c!=EOF)
  {

  }
  line++;
}
```

.y file

```
%{
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include "y.tab.h"
    extern int yylex();
    extern FILE *yyin;
%}


%token L_THAN G_THAN EQUAL L_EQ_THAN G_EQ_THAN NEQUAL
%token ASSIGN
%token LPAREN RPAREN LSQUARE_BRACK RSQUARE_BRACK
%token END_LINE COMMA COLON
%token INDENT DEDENT


%start Program
%%

Program: Block Program
    | Empty
    ;

Empty: /* empty */
    ;

Block: Declarations
    | Subprograms
    | Sequence
    ;



%%
extern int column;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    yyin = fopen("test_code.sy", "r");
    if(yyparse()==1)
        printf("\nParsing failed\n\n");
       else
        printf("\nParsing completed successfully\n");
       fclose(yyin);
    return 0;
}

int yyerror(s)
char *s;
{
                printf("%s\n", s);
        fflush(stdout);
        return 1;
}
```

**EDIT:**sym_tab.h file

```
/*#include <iostream.h>*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

#define table_size          100

extern int line=1;
extern int end_file=1;
extern int block_num=0;
extern FILE *new_file; 

typedef struct hash_sym
    {
    struct hash_sym *prev, *next;
    char *nam;
    char *str_val;
    char *id_type;
    int  id_value;
    int  block_num;
} Hashing_table; 


Hashing_table *table[table_size];

int hash_funct( char str[], int hash_size);

addsym( sym, bloc_num )
register char sym[];
int bloc_num;

{   
    int hash_val = hash_funct( sym, table_size );
    register struct hash_sym *sym_sym = table[hash_val];
    register struct hash_sym *new_sym;
    register struct hash_sym *successor;

    while ( sym_sym!=0 )
    {

        if (  strcmp( sym, table[hash_val]->nam )==0 )
        {   

            printf("the entry %s at line %d already exists at symbol table\n", sym,line);   
            return -1;
        }   

        sym_sym = sym_sym->next;
    }


    new_sym = (struct hash_sym *)
    malloc( sizeof( struct hash_sym ) );


    if ( (successor = table[hash_val]) )
    { 

        new_sym->next = successor;
        successor->prev = new_sym;
    }
    else
        new_sym->next = NULL;

    new_sym->prev = NULL;
    new_sym->nam = sym;
    new_sym->block_num = bloc_num;

    table[hash_val] = new_sym;
    return 0;
}




int hash_funct( str, hash_size )
register char str[];
int hash_size;
{
    register int hashval;
    register int i;

    hashval = 0;
    i = 0;

    while ( str[i]!='\0' )
        {
        hashval = hashval +  str[i++]*(16+i);
        /*hashval %= hash_size;*/
        }
    return (hashval %= hash_size);

}
```

I expected the parser to parse until the end of the file. I haven't setup the prints yet in my .y file so i wouldn't expect a print in there.

Comment: I'd suspect a bug in `addsym` because I don't see anything in the code you pasted which would cause you to run out of memory. But note that `while(c=input()!='\n' && c!=EOF)` (in `comment`) does not do what you think it does. (I don't think that's your problem but you should fix it because it will create serious problems.)

Comment: Also, fix your grammar. Bison resolves conflicts automatically, but the resolution is often not what you want.

Comment: One final note: `yyparse` returns 0 on success and some other value on failure. There is no guarantee that the error return is 1; if it fails because the parse stack is full, it returns 2 (but this precise value is not guaranteed). So the test `if (yyparse() == 1)` is not correct

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Regarding the addsym function, I don't see any way it could cause any issues, it's a built-in function in Flex that adds symbols to the Symbol Table. I have attached my sym_tab.h file in the question, it's the file that makes the function call. @rici

Comment: You really should find less Jurassic code to use as a base. Non-prototyped functions haven't been a thing for 30 years. But that's not your problem either; I guess it is one of the multitude of parse conflicts that is causing your parse stack to overflow, presumably with empty productions. In part, that's the result of your unnecessary attempt to make your grammar right recursive, which also has the effect of increasing stack usage. So solve all those conflicts and prefer left recursion. Then you can start working on the logic errors in your actions.

Comment: Can you provide me a small example of how to make any grammar rule of mine left recursive? @rici

Comment: `Program: Program Block | %empty` (The non-terminal `Empty: ` is unnecessary and should be eliminated.

Comment: By the way, the symbol table functions are not "built-in to flex". I don't know what gave you that idea.

Comment: I assumed that, because the sym_tab file just calls the addsym function and there is no declaration of it in any of the "user-made" file.
Could you think of a reason why we get that "Memory Exhausted" error after the first line? We have changed our grammar rules to be left recursive but to no avail. We get less shift-reduce conflicts, although we still get the exact same error. We can't find a way to reduce our conflicts more. @rici

Comment: You don't need to `strdup()` all the single-character special characters. Just copy `yytext[0]`: indeed, return it immediately to the parser, which should refer to it directly as `'+'`, `'-'`, etc, meaning that you don't need ADD, SUBTRACT, .... You also don't need explicit rules for illegal identifiers or invalid keywords. A final rule of `. return yytext[0]` will cover that *and* all the special characters too. The parser will treat the illegal characters as syntax errors, and you get the benefit of better error recovery.

Comment: Do not vandalize your question. Accept the answer if you want to indicate it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that your grammar includes an arbitrary repetition of a non-terminal which can match the empty string.

That's always ambiguous, because it is impossible to distinguish between an empty string and two consecutive empty strings, or indeed a million consecutive empty strings. So repetition of a nullable non-terminal will always produce a conflict. Most of the time, the generated parser is just incorrect, but it still terminates. Bison resolves shift/reduce conflicts by choosing to shift, which guarantees that the parser will progress through the input. In effect, it resolves the question "how many empty strings are there" with the smallest possible answer, typically "one".

But in your case, the repetition has more than one alternative, several of which are nullable. Now the parser has an even harder problem: it has to figure out which non-terminal the empty string should match. That's a reduce/reduce conflict, and bison's resolution is to always pick the non-terminal which comes first in the grammar. That's going to be a problem if the correct choice for a particular input is some other non-terminal.

Here's a minimal example of what I'm talking about:

```
%%
list: %empty | unit list
unit: as | bs
as: %empty | as 'a'
bs: %empty | bs 'b'
```

Here, a `unit` can be zero or more `a`s, or zero or more `b`s. Since zero `a`s and zero `b`s look identical, the parser really can't tell which one to choose from the grammar, so it always picks zero `a`s (because that comes first in the grammar). The problem comes when the input contains a `b`. Since the parser never uses the rule `bs: %empty` (in fact, bison warns you about that), it can never apply the rule `bs: bs 'b'`. So faced with a `b`, the parser reduces an empty `as`, makes that into a `unit`, adds it to the `list` and then tries to parse another `unit`. However, nothing has changed; no token has been read so the lookahead is still a `b`. And so the parser will go into an endless loop parsing empty `unit`s containing an empty `as` over and over again.

With the `list` production written as above (right recursively), these empty `unit`s need to be added to the parser stack. So the parser will eventually run out of space for its stack, and die with a "memory exhausted" error. If you change it to left recursion (`list: %empty | list unit`), then the parser doesn't need to use stack space, and it can go on parsing empty `unit`s forever.

I suggest that you try the above simple example using bison's very useful trace feature (see ["Debugging your parser"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Debugging) in the Bison Manual). That's a lot easier than filling your grammar file with `printf` calls, and it is also a lot more informative.

To fix the problem, you just need to require `unit` to be non-empty, which avoids the "repetition of an empty string' problem. If every `unit` needs to match something, then the grammar matches the same language but it does so unambiguously.